# Openlayers GIS - Georeferenced DEM(GeoTIFF) not positioned correctly in Map (OpenStreetMap)

Tags: gis, openlayers, openstreetmap, geotiff, openlayers-6

With Openlayers, I'm visualizing GIS rasters(DEM, Orthomosaic) in **GeoTIFF** format(using WebGLTileLayer) on top of OSM(as WebGLTile layer) in OL Map.

The issue I'm having is, the GIS rasters which have georeferencing, are not positioned in its correct geographic position on the OSM base map. The DEM seems to appear in nowhere, around gulf areas or on top of water bodies.

I've created OSM layer with it's default projection & I'm setting view after raster source is loaded, using **source.getView()**

I referred to Raster reprojection examples in the Openlayers website, but wasnt able to solve this.

Does anyone have an idea on how to resolve this?

Comment: Have you included the proj4 definitions for the DEM projections?

Comment: No, but it seems to be automatically detecting the DEM projection, when i check source.getView().getProjection()

Comment: @Mike also, my DEMs can be anywhere in the world, that case how do i define projections in proj4 for the same.

Comment: If you knew all the sources were UTM it would be possible to predefine all 60 for both north and south in a loop as the zone appears in both the code and definition, e.g. that could be done for sentinel sources such as those in https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/multiple-cogs.html  Otherwise you would need to use a look up service https://codesandbox.io/s/multiple-cogs-forked-y6ny9k?file=/main.js

Answer (score 0):

As Mike had suggested in the comments, this issue was happening since even though the projection name was identified from the raster - Eg: "EPSG:3237", the Openlayers library doesnt have the projection definition(what it actually means), so now I'm fetching proj definition from epsg.io & registering in proj4 defs. Now it works perfectly!

Thanks Mike.